# How to backup the iPhone app data, permanently

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, backup

In my app  in  document directory, i have two things, first is sqlite to manage database and i have some images directly saved in document folder by user(only local database).

I updated and inserted the images information through sqlite, now the project requirement is that I have to keep that data alive when app get deleted from device and reinstalled, or suppose user has two device then she can use first device data in second one directly from any way,  so what should i do for this? In my app there  is neither login functionality to identify user specific data nor I have any server to store data. 
Now how to handle this situation to backup the data, any suggestion or related tutorial link would be appreciable.

Comment: I don't see any way around storing the data on a server.  Create a log in mechanic. If you don't want to make accounts, maybe use facebook to authenticate users.

Comment: Thanks Boundless it's sounds good to use fackbook but please tell then  how to backup data and then put data back on iPhone when user reinstall the app.

Comment: Hi, is there any way that i can use user's iCloud account to  identify user and  get particular user's data on different devices? Please tell if you know any way for this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are concerned with images you should look into using the Flickr API.  Flickr will let you store images on their server.  The images will persist even if your app gets deleted.  Here's some links to check out 
http://www.flickr.com/help/mobile/ 
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [game center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html) account to identify the user, I see a lot of games use it. Or you can use their icloud account, not sure about that part.

Comment: Thanks for answering vodkhang. is there any way that i can use user's iCloud account to identify user and get particular user's data on different devices? Please tell if you know any way for this, thanks.